Finding upper bound on $\mathbb{P}(|\frac{X}{n}-p|>a)$ for $X\sim Bin(n,p)$
In Jacod & Protter's "Probability Essentials" exercise 5.14, I found the following question
For $X\sim Bin(n,p)$, $p,a>0$, $n\in\mathbb{N}$, show that
\begin{equation}
\mathbb{P}(|\frac{X}{n}-p|>a)<\frac{\sqrt{p(1-p)}}{a^2n}\min(\sqrt{p(1-p)},a\sqrt{n})
\end{equation}
Generally, I want to show that the left hand side is smaller than either of the possible options. The first of which I would have solved with Chebychev's inequality $\mathbb{P}(|X-\mathbb{E}[X]|>a)\leq \frac{\sigma_X^2}{a^2}$ and the fact that $\sigma_{X/n}^2=\frac{1}{n^2}\sigma_X^2\leq \frac{\sigma_X^2}{n}$.
For the second part I have to prove
\begin{equation}
\mathbb{P}(|\frac{X}{n}-p|>a)<\frac{\sqrt{p(1-p)}}{a \sqrt{n}},
\end{equation}
but going for Chebychev related inequations hasn't brought me to a valid idea so I would ask you for any advice how I could begin in order to arrive at something that results in these roots.
Any help is much appreciated!
Thanks
Leo

Let's do both parts, by first rewriting LHS as $\mathbb P[|X-pn|>an]=\mathbb P[|X-\mathbb E[X]|>\lambda]$, where $\lambda=an$. This is a more comfortable setup. We know that $\sigma=\sigma(X)=\sqrt{np(1-p)}$ and $\mu=\mathbb E[X]=np$.
For the first part,
$$\mathbb P\big[|X-\mu|>\lambda\big]<\frac{\sigma^2}{\lambda^2}= \frac{np(1-p)}{a^2n^2}=\frac{\sqrt{p(1-p)}}{a^2n}\cdot\sqrt{p(1-p)}=:p_1$$
The second part is kind of weird. Define $p_1$ as written above, and observe
$$p_2:=\frac{\sqrt{p(1-p)}}{a^2n}\cdot a\sqrt n=\sqrt{\frac{p(1-p)}{a^2n}}=\sqrt{p_1}$$
This means that the question is asking you to prove:
$$\mathbb P\big[|X-\mu|>\lambda\big]\leq \min(\sqrt{p_1},p_1)$$
But this is clearly true for any value of $p_1$ because if $p_1\leq 1$ then $\sqrt{p_1}\geq p_1>\mathbb P[|X-\mu|>\lambda]$ and if $p_1>1$ then $\sqrt{p_1}>1\geq \mathbb P[|X-\mu|>\lambda]$.
